# How do I control the AutomationProperties.Name of a Button, such that the value does not use multiple lines?

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml

Suppose I have this XAML in a WinRT app:

```
<Button Content="&#xE109;" AutomationProperties.Name="Add A New Thing" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" />
```

Because the value of AutomationProperties.Name is so long, the text on the button spans two lines. I would like it to stay on a single line. I tried expanding the width of the button to something that would definitely be wide enough for the text, but the text seemed to want to continue to be on two lines. What is the markup I should add to this Button control to keep the text on a single line?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this stumped me. Here's what I tried:

```
<StackPanel>
    <!-- Standard -->
    <AppBarButton Label="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"></AppBarButton>
    <!-- &#160; -->
    <AppBarButton Label="The&#160;quick&#160;brown&#160;fox&#160;jumps&#160;over&#160;the&#160;lazy&#160;dog"></AppBarButton>
    <!-- Underscore -->
    <AppBarButton Label="The_quick_brown_fox_jumps_over_the_lazy_dog"></AppBarButton>
</StackPanel>
```

Each attempt resulted in the exact same result, text wrapping.

This leaves you with two options.

1. Stop using such long strings
2. Update the template

So, since you will want to be using an `AppBarButton` instead of a standard Button with an AppBar style, I'll cater my answer to Windows 8.1 and Visual Studio 2013. I don't have 2012 anyway.

The template (just right click the control in the designer and select Edit Template / Copy. You will find this line, near the bottom:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TextLabel" 
Foreground="{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}"
FontSize="12" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" TextAlignment="Center"
TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Label}" Width="88"/>
```

You can see it is set to wrap. Just change `TextWrapping="Wrap"` to `TextWrapping="NoWrap"` and you'll get what you want. Then just make sure all your buttons use the template you have edited (so you might want to relocate it up to app.xaml).

It's that easy, really.

PS: you might be tempted to use a WPF trick of `TextBlock.TextWrapping="NoWrap"` on the primary control. This does not work, so I can save you time trying.

Best of luck!